Psalm 23:6 meaning
I encountered a very depressing word study that says that the end of Psalm 23:6, "forever" is not infinite, but more on the lines of "all my days" ...
Other sources say this shows eternal life in the Old Testament (I would certainly want that to be true).
Does anyone know what the word that is forever in the NKJV means?
The more infinite the meaning is, the better ...
Psalm 23:6 NKJV

Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me All the days of my life; And I will dwell in the house of the LORD Forever.

Reference about Psalm 23:6

The Hebrew may be expressed as 'length of days' (see Biblehub and also Young's Literal Translation) which is all that is revealed in the Old Testament. It is the New Testament which opens up the concept of eternal life. ... our Saviour Jesus Christ, who hath abolished death, and hath brought life and immortality to light through the gospel: 2 Timothy 1:10. Up-voted +1.

I see no reason what the heart of the psalmist (or his poetry) is diminished by the less infinite meaning of the word. One is always free to interpret it in the manner suggested by @NigelJ

@DanFefferman if you're used to the N/KJV translation of Forever and it is changed to "length of days" that's quite a downgrade, especially if you want to use it as prooftext for eternal life in the OT.  Of course, this isn't a knock on the poetry, I like the shepherd imagery, which implies we are his sheep (see Ps. 100).  I've heard someone say that the KJV translation was inspired, and I'd like to think so, and that this carries onto the NKJV!

The Hebrew may be expressed as 'length of days' , see Biblehub and also Young's Literal Translation, which is all that is revealed in the Old Testament.
It is the New Testament which opens up the concept of eternal life :

... our Saviour Jesus Christ, who hath abolished death, and hath brought life and immortality to light through the gospel [2 Timothy 1:10 KJV]


Nice comparison of scripture with scripture.

The final phrase of Ps 23:6 is literally:

בְּבֵית־יְ֝הוָ֗ה לְאֹ֣רֶךְ יָמִֽים = in the house of YHWH until length of days

The final two words also occur in Ps 21:4 -

He asked life of You, You gave it to him, Length of days forever
and ever.

There is a similar idea in Ps 27:4 -

One thing I have asked of the LORD; this is what I desire: to dwell in
the house of the LORD all the days of my life, to gaze on the beauty
of the LORD and seek Him in His temple.

The phrase, לְאֹ֣רֶךְ יָמִֽים = "until length of days", is Hebrew idiom meaning, "all the days of my life".  this conclusion is further strengthened by its synthetic parallel in the first part of the verse which looks like this:

Surely goodness and mercy shall follow me all the days of my life
And I shall dwell in the house of the LORD until length of days

The idea of eternity is explicitly absent in this text; indeed, the usual word commonly meaning "forever" is עוֹלָם (olam) is also absent.  Further, the Bible data about the details of heaven (for the saved saints) is rather scant - see appendix below.
The pulpit commentary on Ps 23:6 says this:

Such passages are, of course, not to be understood literally; they
express the longing of the soul for a sense of the continual presence
of God, and a realization of constant communion with him.

APPENDIX - Heaven
Here we want to discuss the idea of heaven as the destiny for the righteous; that is the “third heaven” (2 Cor 12:2-4).  The very scant Biblical data on this idea is found in:

2 Peter 3 describes three “worlds”.  The first was the antediluvian world which was destroyed by water.  The second is our world which will destroyed by fire to be replaced by the third world consisting of a new heaven and new earth.
Heb 11:16 talks about a better country, a heavenly one, that is, designed and constructed (perfectly) by God.  However, the location is not disclosed.
John 14:2, 3 talks about rooms in the Father’s house but does not mention heaven.  However, Jesus says He came from heaven (John 3:13, 1 Cor 15:47, John 6:41) and this passage tells that Jesus returning there to prepare a place (in quintessential wedding imagery) and will come back to take us there.
Col 3:1-4 discusses Christ seated at the right hand of God and the saints appearing with Him in glory.  Again, heaven is not mentioned explicitly but implied.
1 Thess 4:16, 17 promises that the Lord will descend from heaven and the saints will be caught up to meet the Lord, in “clouds”, “in the air”.
Isa 65:17 promises unmitigated happiness and joy of a great and noble kind because former problems will not be remembered.  Matt 5:12.  However, whether the saints will be in “heaven” or on earth is not stated.
Rev 20:1-6 gives a further hint by promising important things such as the saints reigning with Jesus (where is not stated) while the wicked are dead on earth.  Following the 1000 years (Rev 21:1-4), the New Jerusalem descends from heaven to earth.  In this act heaven and earth are merged.
The book of Ephesians presents an interesting view of “heavenly places”


o  Eph 6:12 - because to us the wrestling is not against blood and flesh, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers of this darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.




o  Eph 3:10 - His purpose was that now, through the church, the manifold wisdom of God should be made known to the rulers and authorities in the heavenly realms,




o  Eph 1:3 - Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly realms.




o  Eph 2:6 - and He raised us up together and seated us together in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus



Thus, among other things, the heavenly realms/places contain spiritual forces of evil!  (This is almost certainly Jewish idiom??)
Further, while heaven as a place is described in many Bible passages, especially Revelation, all such descriptions are clearly quite symbolic.
Thus, we know very little of heaven, presumably because it is beyond description!
However, there is one very important piece of information about which there is no doubt.  The reward of the righteous is to be with Jesus 1 Thess 4:17, Rev 21:4, 5.  Indeed, it is this very prospect that so fills the righteous with unspeakable joy (Isa 25:9) and the wicked with so much anguish that they request destruction (Rev 6:15-17).  Both groups have their wish granted.
The Bible appears to be far more concerned about the character of the inhabitants of heaven than the details of heaven itself.

God is present personally, Rev 21:1-4, John 14:3
People commune directly and personally with God, Rev 22:4.
Only Righteous people live in heaven, Rev 21:7, 8, 2 Peter 3:13.
Nothing impure or unclean enters the New Jerusalem, Rev 21:27.

Thus, heaven will not be a repeat of the imperfect governments on earth.  Heaven is ruled by a perfect and benevolent God who is kind, gracious and omniscient.  Rev 11:15.
